# Reducing and checking for the longest string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Heyo everyone, so I have this exercises where I need to check which string is the longest in the array. This code works, but I am not 100% sure if understand the reduce part of it. So correct me if I'm wrong - when the reduce begins the total is 'the' and the num is 'quick' and because 'the' is shorter than 'quick' it returns 'quick'. So the next time total is 'quick' and num is 'brown'?

```
function findLongestWord(str) {

var arr = str.split(' ');

var longest = arr.reduce(function(total, num){

  if(total.length>num.length){
    return total;
  } else {
    return num;
  }

});    


return longest.length;

}

findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

Comment: what about two string which are the longest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {

var arr = str.split(' ');

var longest = arr.reduce(function(total, num){
  console.log('total :', total,'num :',  num);
  if(total.length>num.length){
    return total;
  } else {
    return num;
  }

});    


return longest.length;

}

findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

it keeps taking the elements of the array pair by pair and stores the bigger variable in total, the newer string to be compared is num, since it us compared in a pairwise fashion, it it would return the longest string

Comment: Thank you! Probably the best 'explanation' about reducing :D

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Reduce works by applying the function to every two elements from left to right.